# Click and call javaScript function using A-Frame

Tags: javascript, aframe

I want to call two function in javaScript using aframe. Here is my code

```
AFRAME.registerComponent('house-hold', {
schema: {
    type: 'selectorAll',
    default: null
  },
init: function () {
    this.entities = [];

    if ( this.data === null ) {
      this.entities.push(this.el);
    } else {
      this.entities = this.data;
    }
   this.toggleHandler = this.toggleVisibility.bind(this);
},

play: function() {
  this.el.addEventListener('click', this.toggleHandler);
},

pause: function() {
    this.el.removeEventListener('click', this.toggleHandler);
},
hide: function(entities){
var entities = this.entities;
var cursor = this.el.sceneEl.querySelector('[cursor]');
for (var i = 0; i < entities.length; i++) {

        entities[i].object3D.visible = false;

        entities[i].pause();

        entities[i].classList.remove('clickable');
        entities[i].classList.add('clickable-disabled');
        cursor.components.raycaster.refreshObjects();

      } 
 },
 show: function(entities){
var entities = this.entities;
var cursor = this.el.sceneEl.querySelector('[cursor]');
for (var i = 0; i < entities.length; i++) {

        entities[i].object3D.visible = true;

        entities[i].play();

        entities[i].classList.remove('clickable-disabled');
        entities[i].classList.add('clickable');
        cursor.components.raycaster.refreshObjects();

      }
 },
toggleVisibility: function(e) {   
  var categoryScene = document.querySelectorAll('#category-scene');
  var houseHoldCareScene = document.querySelectorAll('#house-hold-scene');
  var personalCareScene = document.querySelectorAll('#personal-care-scene');
  var toasterScene = document.querySelectorAll('#toaster-scene');
  var cursor = this.el.sceneEl.querySelector('[cursor]');
  show(houseHoldCareScene);
  hide(categoryScene);
  hide(personalCareScene);
  hide(toasterScene);
   }
  });
```

This is my code. I called hide and show function. But it did not work. Clicking also did not work.I think my calling method is not correct. When I click it should work but it did not. How can I call that two function properly? How to solve this problem?

Cursor I made like this

```
<a-camera position="2 -2.5 12">

  <!-- Only make entities with class="clickable" clickable. -->
  <a-cursor raycaster="objects: .clickable" 
            fuse-timeout="2000"
            material="color: #F4D03F; shader: flat" 
            opacity="0.9">

    <!-- CLICK & FUSE ANIMATIONS -->
    <a-animation begin="click" easing="ease-in" attribute="scale" dur="150" fill="forwards" from="0.1 0.1 0.1" to="1 1 1"></a-animation>
    <a-animation begin="cursor-fusing" easing="ease-in" attribute="scale" dur="1500" fill="backwards" from="1 1 1" to="0.1 0.1 0.1"></a-animation>

  </a-cursor>

</a-camera>
```

Comment: could you post the way you made the cursor ?

Comment: I have posted. I made like that.

Comment: it should be working - like it is in my fiddle, https://jsfiddle.net/qq0whbvz/5/, did you put `console.log`'s at the beginning of the functions to check if they are called ?

Comment: I think the function and calling method have problem. Can you check that?

Comment: try adding the eventlistener in the init function

Comment: Can you please check hide and show function? Because that is the main problem. some times that function doesn't work and calling method  also.

Answer (score 0):

You have to call your functions using the `this` pointer since they are methods of the component, not global function declarations:

```
this.show(houseHoldCareScene);
this.hide(categoryScene);
this.hide(personalCareScene);
```

Comment: No. It's not working. It's not clicking also. houseHoldCareScene, this should show but it's not showing.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, calling functions defined in the component, need to have the `this` keyword, because they are encapsulated in the component, and not global (like D.Marcos said in his anwser).

Second of all, You need to have your event listener made on `init`, if You want it to work right away:

```
init: function() {
   // your current code (...)
   this.toggleHandler = this.toggleVisibility.bind(this);
   this.el.addEventListener('click', this.toggleHandler);
}
```

The play, and pause functions are called when entering / exiting the inspector as far as i know.

Comment: Can you give me example please? And how to write event listener on init?

Comment: @SabbirHossain updated, please add a `console.log()` to the toggleHandler to check if it's registering clicks properly

Comment: Then not need to use play and pause function? Actually there are multiple scene. When one scene is hide I need to remove event listener.

Comment: @SabbirHossain the play and pause functions are common in other components / systems (like when you enter / exit the `inspector`) so it's a good thing to implement them like you did. If you want to remove the event listeners use `pause`, or any other function which is removing the event listeners. When accessing it from outside the component, call it like this: `entity.components.house-hold.pause()`

Comment: Okay I understand. But my hide and show function are not working properly. What's the wrong?

Comment: @SabbirHossain are they even called ? did you try to check it with a log ?